# mount GCPs buckets with write access

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcsfuse

I can successfully mount my bucket using the following command

```
sudo mount -t gcsfuse -o rw,noauto,user,implicit_dirs,allow_other fakebucket thebucket/
```

I can go into the bucket find the subfolders and etc. however I can't write anything

> touch: cannot touch 'aaa': Permission denied

I have tried to use various parameters in the gcsfuse for example `rw,noauto,user,implicit_dirs,allow_other` - even I tried a regular chmod command after

```
sudo chmod -R 777 thebucket/
```

with no error, but the permission has not changed, neither I can write into the bucket.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are having might be because of three things:

-Permissions on the OS after mounting, to solve this mount your bucket with the following command:

`sudo mount -t gcsfuse -o implicit_dirs,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000 <BUCKET> <PATH>`

-Permissions of your service account, to validate this you can go on the consolen to IAM & admin and verify that the service account your VM is using has Storage Admin Role.

-Cloud API Access Scopes: verify under the VM configuration that it has read write or full access for storage.

Comment: Cloud API Access Scopes changes worked for me. Default Scopes are not sufficient and need to be broadened.

Comment: when I edit my VM all I see is: "Access scopes
Use IAM roles with service accounts to control VM access. Learn more" but there is no button or way of setting the "scopes".  how is this to be done?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the scopes of the service account used by the instance, by default the access to  Cloud Storage is read only.